# How to exclude specific div simple html dom?

Tags: php, html, xpath, simple-html-dom

How should I exclude a specific `div` children from being printed out?

Example: from the below code, the parent div is called `<div class="event-panel">` and it has children `div`s that are `<div class="details">`, `<div class="games">` and `<div class="wrap">`.

So what I want is that all divs inside  should not be printed out for example, like this `<div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>` and all the others that will be inside a wrapper div, I have used this method which should work but I don't know where I am wrong .

The parent div should be removed `<div class="event-panel">`, see the code below.

**HTML structure:**

```html
<div class="event-panel">
  <div class="details">
    <div class="event-date">22:00</div>
    <div class="event-name">Serie A 2017 v Winner</div>
  </div>
  <div class="games">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="full-event-button" onclick="prestige('/event  /3123361')">+1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Executed code:**

```php
<?php
include ('advanced_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://sport.premierbet.com/tz/sport/1/#');

//Counting number of empty-outcome
$emptv = count($gameone = $html->find('div[class="empty-outcome"]'));
echo "Number of empty attribute is " . $emptv . '<br>';

//Print any data that i want but exclude this <div class="empty-outcome">&nbsp;</div>
foreach ($html->find('empty-outcome') as $item)
{
    $item->outertext = '';
    $ret = $item->find('div[class="event-name"]');
    echo "Event Name " . $ret . "<br>";
}

$html->clear();

?>
```

Comment: Wilson, you don't want these divs to print on screen or literally print (i.e. 
 from printer)

Comment: :-) :-) i mean i dont want them to be printed when i `echo` or `print` on screen @Rushikumar

Comment: oh okay... why not add the class of the div to your CSS and simply say `display: none;`?

Comment: I'm scraping from other site i don't think if that is possible.

Comment: Any suggestion @Obsidian Age

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong css, it should be:

```
$html->find('.empty-outcome')
```

also here's a shortcut for removing those:

```
$html->find('.empty-outcome')->remove;
```

Comment: What if i want the entire div including parent div `<div class="event-panel">` to be removed? and at the top there are other div with same class name how to instruct that div parent `<div class="event-panel">` containing `<div class="empty-outcome">` because if you instruct to remove `<div class="event-panel">` only it will remove other div with same class name that are at the top and with the codes you write above i think it will remove the class only which is `<div class="empty-outcome">` the parent will remain but i want it to be removed also. @pguardiario

Comment: I'm not sure I followed that but these are css questions so I recommend brushing up on css,